# What chrome policy blocks URL API requests of websites?

Tags: api, google-chrome, url, browser, policy

I have a problem here with policies that I can't deal with.

I use SafeSitesFilterBehavior policy to filter adult content in Chrome and it works well, but when I use URL capture screenshot websites like this (https://www.site-shot.com) to enter the URL of the adult site, it generates a screenshot with that adult site. And there are plenty of “URL to screenshots” websites on the web. Also a multitude of websites with services like URL to PDF, or URL to video file, that generates that PDF or that video file.

I also tried to add the adult sites in the hosts file, and the problems still presist.

So, I am asking you, if you are kind to answer me, what policy should I use in Chrome so it can blocks API requests for these kind of websites, becaue I think API is the problem here that generates the screenshots of the URL and ignores SafeSitesFilterBehavior policy.

Thank you in advance!

I expect to find out a chrome policy that blocks API requests of websites like URL to PNG or URL to PDF, or URL to Video file.